# Case opening in a new chrome tab instead of Salesforce tab

Tags: javascript, softphone, phone

I am using Phone-to-Case in Salesforce and whenever a customer calls, I want a new tab to be opened in Salesforce.

`window.open("https://enovos--vocalcom.lightning.force.com/" + result[0].id, "_BLANK");`

I added the id of the case at the end of the link.
Before the case is opened in a new chrome tab, the current salesforce page shows me this error page:
[image]

And then it opens the new case in a new chrome tab and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

When we use "_Blank" URL is loaded into a new window, or tab. If you want the default behavior to load into new tab only use it without the "_Blank" parameter.

> window.open("https://enovos--vocalcom.lightning.force.com/" +
> result[0].id);

Comment: I tried and it's the same behavior.